# How would I make python store the data of multiple people?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm tryna make a discord.py async bot that will award people with brownie points (heh heh) when asked. It's supposed to be a local bot for my friends and me, but I don't want to update every single brownie point of every person into the code every time I restart it. My code is here:

import commands

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time
import random

#Here is the basic command:
#await client.send_message(message.channel, messsage)

#global hub
me = 0
discordname = "PRIVATE"

Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("the brownies are loaded and ready to go!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("bb! give"):
        args = message.content.split(" ")
        if args[1:][1] == "(my user ID)":
            global me
            global discordname
            me = me + int(args[1:][2])
            await client.send_message(message.channel, str(int(args[1:][2])) + "  brownie points have been given to " + str(discordname))
    if message.content.startswith("bb! brownies"):
        args = message.content.split(" ")
        if args[1:][1] == "(my user ID)":
            await client.send_message(message.channel, str(discordname) + " 
currently has " + str(me) + " brownie points.")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

I wanna make the bot create a new variable each time a user joins the server. However, every attempt I've tried (i.e. pickle module, shelve module...) has turned one of the following consequences:

1. It does nothing
2. It malfunctions
3. It returns an error

Comment: You should include the errors within your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you importing the `commands` extension if you're not using it?  Utilize the `commands` extension and pull your code out of the `on_message` event. This lets you take advantage of some of the cool features of the `commands` extension, like [converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters)

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import discord
from collections import defaultdict

bot = Bot('!')

points = defaultdict(int)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def give(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    points[member.id] += 1
    bot.say("{} now has {} points".format(member.mention, points[member.id]))

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def points(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    bot.say("{} has {} points".format(member.mention, points[member.id]))

bot.run('token')
```

As far as persisting your data, you have a few options. You could write the data to a file, and read it back, but I would instead suggest looking into setting up a database.  There are plenty of resources online elsewhere and on this site that can show you how. If you do go that route, you should probably use an asynchronoues database library like [`asyncpg`](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg).